# I can't adjust the size of an image. I have tried by giving both width:150px and also width:150% instead of width:150px. it doesn't make sense

Tags: html, css

---

This is my code css code.

---

```
    img[src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/colored-powder-explosion-on-black-background-picture-id1140180560?k=20&m=1140180560&s=612x612&w=0&h=X_400OQDFQGqccORnKt2PHYvTZ3dBLeEnCH_hRiUQrY"]{
width:250px;
}
```

---

This is my html code

---

```
      <img  src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/colored-powder-explosion-on-black-background-picture-id1140180560?k=20&m=1140180560&s=612x612&w=0&h=X_400OQDFQGqccORnKt2PHYvTZ3dBLeEnCH_hRiUQrY=">
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It is very hard to answer your code, especially when you don't explain it or even give HTML code to help. It looks like it's because you added an extra `'` after `src="`. Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i have given my html code now...

Comment: i can change the image size when i give src='image.jpg'. but i can't chance when i copy paste the image adress directly from google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector is different to the actual `src`. The code below fixes this problem and has the exact `src`.

The difference was that you appended an unnecessary `=` to the selector in CSS.

```css
img[src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/colored-powder-explosion-on-black-background-picture-id1140180560?k=20&m=1140180560&s=612x612&w=0&h=X_400OQDFQGqccORnKt2PHYvTZ3dBLeEnCH_hRiUQrY="] {
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/colored-powder-explosion-on-black-background-picture-id1140180560?k=20&m=1140180560&s=612x612&w=0&h=X_400OQDFQGqccORnKt2PHYvTZ3dBLeEnCH_hRiUQrY=">
```

A better way would be to use `.classes {}` or `#ids {}` though.

More information about attribute selectors: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

More information about: [Classes - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) [IDs - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors)